# Помогите понять логику цикла while

Tags: c++, while

изучая с++ я столкнулся с непонятной для меня проблемой в цикле `while` а именно с бесконечным зацикливанием его на одной команде игнорируя остальные", при вводе с клавиатуры любой переменной типа `string`.

```
int cint()
{
    int are = 0;
    cout << "введите длину пароля (от 8 до 128)" << endl;
    while (are < 1)
    {
        cin >> are;
        if (are <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Ошибка, вы ввели не верное число! Пожалуйста введите число ещё раз: ";// команда на которой всё и зацикливается
        }
        else if (are > 0);
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return are;
}
```

Буду очень рад если вы объясните причину такого поведения программы или подскажите оптимальное решение данной проблемы.

Comment: Решение проблемы -- начать с `while (cin >> are) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что тут понимать?

```
cin >> are;
```

При вводе чего-то, что не является `int`ом, поток переходит в состояние `fail`, и больше ничего не читает. `are` не меняется. Условие `are<1` остается верным, `are>0`, наоборот, неверным.

Цикл крутится...

Такое устроит?

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите дину пароля",8,128);
```